# Create a new listener for a specific event of my workflow

Tags: email, events, customization, jira

I'm trying to add a listener which could send an e-mail to users when a specific event occurs in my workflow. I saw in the menu System, then listeners submenu, a list of 3 internal listeners... but I don't know how to create mine, and modify ths script if it is required.

Is this possible with a listener to send an e-mail to a reporter every day following an event, at 01:00pm. For example, waiting for an action of reporter, and when this action will be made, JIRA no longer sends him this e-mail ....

Any help appreciated,

Christophe

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you use a Jira instance which is installed locally you could write your own listener with a logic you need as described here https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Writing+JIRA+Event+Listeners+with+the+atlassian-event+Library and define a custom event as described here https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Adding+a+Custom+Event. However as far as I know this is not actual for Atlassian OnDemand version.

I suggest to consider the option of using filter subscription instead. You could create a common filter for all users e.g.:
    `project=TST and reporter=currentUser() and status in ("Action Required") ORDER BY Priority DESC`

After that save this filter as public, subscribe all needed users to it so they will be receiving the list of issues to process. Here is the link for more details on filter subscription https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Receiving+Search+Results+via+Email. Hope this will be helpful for you.